# korn shell: How to process a command in processing a command?

Tags: linux, shell, ksh

Hello folks!
First a code I have now:

```sh
for CLSGRPID in `${${`/usr/bin/snmpwalk \
    -v 1 -c $COMM $HOST $OID.11.1.1.1`##*:}%\n} | xargs` ; do
```

I'd like to first process

```
/usr/bin/snmpwalk -v 1 -c $COMM $HOST $OID.11.1.1.1
```

which used alone returns lines

```
.2.3.1.2.1.5.11.1.1.1.1 = INTEGER: 1
.2.3.1.2.1.5.11.1.1.1.2 = INTEGER: 2
.2.3.1.2.1.5.11.1.1.1.3 = INTEGER: 3
```

and then for every return line I'd like to cut it like `${line##*:}` and then from the other side `${line%\n}` and then all of those lines put to `xargs` and process it.
So requested output would be

```
1 2 3
```

Is it possible? Please get me some ideas how to do it.

Comment: It's pretty hard to tell what you're trying to accomplish here. Please consider editting  your post to include 1. sample data, 2. required output given that sample data. 3. current output. 4. commnents why its wrong. Also, join the 90's and use ksh `$( ... )` form of cmd-substitution instead of back-ticks. Also, doesn't `xargs` require a command to operate on? Good luck.

Comment: @shellter you're right, output is also important. It's added.

Comment: so the result would be `for CLSGRPID in 1 2 3 ; do ... ` ?

Comment: Probably yes. I want for every for round one of these numbers, so I hope when it gets 1 2 3, it does 3 rounds, with 1, with 2 and with 3

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`net-snmp` commands have *many* options that modify their behaviour and output.  I recommend that you read the man pages for each of `snmpcmd`,  `snmpwalk`, and `snmp.conf`.

Check the `-O` option group in `snmpwalk` (see below).

The `-Oqv` combination results in a column with just the numbers:

```
$ clsgrpids=$(
    /usr/bin/snmpwalk -Oqv -v 1 -c $COMM $HOST $OID.11.1.1.1
)
$ echo "$clsgrpids"
1
2
3
```

Remove the quotes to let the shell print a single line:

```
$ echo $clsgrpids
1 2 3
```

Here are the remaining options in the `-O` option group that control the output for `snmpwalk`:

```
-O OUTOPTS
        Toggle various defaults controlling output display:
        0:  print leading 0 for single-digit hex characters
        a:  print all strings in ascii format
        b:  do not break OID indexes down
        e:  print enums numerically
        E:  escape quotes in string indices
        f:  print full OIDs on output
        n:  print OIDs numerically
        q:  quick print for easier parsing
        Q:  quick print with equal-signs
        s:  print only last symbolic element of OID
        S:  print MIB module-id plus last element
        t:  print timeticks unparsed as numeric integers
        T:  print human-readable text along with hex strings
        u:  print OIDs using UCD-style prefix suppression
        U:  don't print units
        v:  print values only (not OID = value)
```

**Verification** (actual running code)

```
$ snmpwalk  -Ov -v1 -c public localhost  sysUptime
Timeticks: (66595) 0:11:05.95
$ snmpwalk  -Oqv -v1 -c public localhost  sysUptime
0:0:11:35.13
$ snmpwalk  -Otqv -v1 -c public localhost  sysUptime
70012
```

Comment: It's almost the thing I need, but still it returns INTEGER: 1 INTEGER: 2 and INTEGER: 3, not 1 2 3

Comment: I originally said to include `-Ov` - this does indeed still include the unit prefix.  I'm editing the answer to include the `q` flag as well, which gives the desired result.

Answer (score 0):

You can use awk.

```
for CLSGRPID in `/usr/bin/snmpwalk -v 1 -c $COMM $HOST $OID.11.1.1.1 | awk '{print $NF}'`; do
    echo $CLSGRPID
done
```

Comment: This does exactly what I want. Thanks!